# mysqli - how many is too many (very slow)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a page that is a survey- based on your answers to previous questions shows and hides other questions using jquery (these questions vary with all input types) I have a save function and then a save and submit function - when saving and submitting I need to verify ALL questions that have not been hidden have been answered - in prototyping this with outputs to test the syntax I realized that the massive quantity of mysqli querys I am running slows the page down (could be upward of 300 questions or as short at 10)

what we have below is a query to find out how many questions are assigned to this survey (sid, $surveyid), $qcountup was my way of making the while statement visit every single number between 1 and the highest question number ($qtotal) 
we get down to the while statement which is reoperating for every number from 1 - $qtotal) inside the while we run a query to find out if an answer exists for each number in the database (if it was not answered - it wont exist. 
again how this is coded currently could mean 300+ mysqli querys (LAG). any suggestions on how to condense this or write it better?

```
    $qquery = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE (sid = ".$surveyid.");";
$qresult = mysqli_query($dbc, $qquery);
$qtotal = mysqli_num_rows($qresult);
$qcountup = 1;
while($qcountup <= $qtotal){
$squery = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE sid='".$SID."' AND question='".$qcountup."';";
$sresult = mysqli_query($dbc, $squery) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($sresult) )
{
echo("<br>row existed");
} else {
echo("<br>row doesn't exist");
}     
$qcountup = $qcountup + 1;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you're using mysqli, you should be using prepared queries rather than interpolating variables directly into the query strings.

The first query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) qtotal FROM question WHERE sid = "$surveyid"
```

If you're only interested in the number, there's no need to get all the columns. Set `$qtotal` to the `qtotal` column of this result.

For the second part, you can use a LEFT JOIN to match questions against answers, and see which answers are missing:

```
SELECT * FROM questions q LEFT JOIN answers a USING (question, sid)
WHERE q.sid = $SID
ORDER BY q.question
```

If an answer is missing, a.question will be NULL in that row.

I'm not sure if I should be using $SID or $surveyid there; your original code used both in different queries.

Comment: sorry not to clarify - I do need the questions too to identify whether terms were met to hide a question - but my other question is can I match the question numbers (in question table identified by qid) to the answer numbers and also is there a way to select an answer by its number later in the statement as if it were an array - (if I need the submitted answer from #23 or something answer[23])

Comment: `$dbc` is just the database connection that was returned by `mysqli_connect()`, it doesn't contain any information. I'll update my answer shortly with a new query that matches questions against answers.

Comment: yeah I saw the $dbc reference just after I hit add comment - I appreciate the help - this is really a topic I am lost on

Comment: $SID was a shop id (unique number for the report) $surveyid was the identifier for what set of questions to use, last question - how would I reference say answer 23 if I needed to call it out of order would it be a.answer[23] since answer is the name of the column containing the answers

Comment: It's really hard to answer your questions without knowing your table structure and how the tables are related. Add it to your question. But basically, you use WHERE clauses to look for specific rows, SQL doesn't have arrays. So `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE sid = $SID AND question = 23` will find answer 23 fro this shop ID.